# DataInputStream from a MappedByteBuffer

Tags: java, memory-mapped-files, bytebuffer, datainputstream

I wonder if it is possible to create DataInputStream backed by a MappedByteBuffer instance ?

```
MappedByteBuffer buff = (initialize...);
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(buff.array());
```

This code snippet throws [UnsupportedOperationException](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CG8QFjAA&url=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html&ei=IX4bULD0OOmn4gTnoYDoAw&usg=AFQjCNGpz54HJPh7w5G3b6LLuk10FHPVaQ) because mapped byte buffer is not backed by an accessible array.

Then I tried to load bytes to pyhsical memory by calling [load](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html#load%28%29) method by it is no use.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override methods in DataInputStream to use the MappedByteBuffer.

However, the simplest approach is to use the MappedByteBuffer directly as it support almost all the same methods.

Comment: I extended InputStream, passed my MappedByteBuffer instance to it and used its methods, so no problem now, thanks for your suggestion :) But I wonder why "load" fails to load buffer's content into physical memory ?